# Two server freezes with in two weeks

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, hardware, kernel

Two consecutive server freezes with in two weeks.

We are running ubuntu 11.04 64bit on  **Intel(R) Xeon(R) E5620 @ 2.40GHz** with 48 Gb RAM on **2.6.38-13-generic** kernel dedicated server.

after making some changes to .htaccess file we **reloaded apache** and system freezed and we couldnt even ssh to it.we waited for some time but we couldn't ssh to it.Later we did a restart.while analyzing the syslog we found **general protection fault: 0000 [#1] SMP** followed by a set of weird messages.we are also running a script as cron on every minute to log total apache children ie **log-children**.

May  2 22:34:11 406831 kernel: [3715446.033031] general protection fault: 0000 [#1] SMP

May  2 22:34:11 406831 kernel: [3715446.054726] last sysfs file: 
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu15/cache/index2/shared_cpu_map

May  2 22:34:11 406831 kernel: [3715446.097404] CPU 5

May  2 22:34:11 406831 kernel: [3715446.097869] Modules linked in: nf_conntrack_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv6 ip6t_LOG xt_tcpudp ipt_REDIRECT xt_conntrack iptable_mangle nf_conntrack_ftp ipt_REJECT ipt_LOG xt_limit xt_multiport xt_state ip6table_filter ip6_tables iptable_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack_ipv4 nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv4 iptable_filter ip_tables x_tables vesafb snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec psmouse ioatdma snd_hwdep i7core_edac ghes edac_core lp hed dca joydev snd_pcm serio_raw parport snd_timer snd soundcore snd_page_alloc usbhid hid e1000e

May  2 22:34:11 406831 kernel: [3715446.279465]

May  2 22:34:11 406831 kernel: [3715446.303429] Pid: 19118, comm: **apache2 Not tainted 2.6.38-13-generic** #56-Ubuntu Supermicro X8DTL/X8DTL

May  2 22:34:11 406831 kernel: [3715446.355544] RIP: 0010:[]  [] task_rq_lock+0x4a/0xa0

May  2 22:34:11 406831 kernel: [3715446.411635] RSP: 0018:ffff88060b853da8  EFLAGS: 00010082

May  2 22:34:11 406831 kernel: [3715446.440241] RAX: 010021b86505c7ff RBX: 0000000000013d00 RCX: 00000001162d8937

May  2 22:34:11 406831 kernel: [3715446.497492] RDX: 0000000000000282 RSI: ffff88060b853df0 RDI: 00007fdac0088280

May  2 22:34:11 406831 kernel: [3715446.559362] RBP: ffff88060b853dc8 R08: 0000000000000040 R09: 001fc00000000000

May  2 22:34:11 406831 kernel: [3715446.625144] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: dead000000100100 R12: 00007fdac0088280

May  2 22:34:11 406831 kernel: [3715446.695569] R13: ffff88060b853df0 R14: 0000000000013d00 R15: 0000000000000005

May  2 22:34:11 406831 kernel: [3715446.770654] FS:  00007fdac0023760(0000) GS:ffff880c3fc20000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000

May  2 22:34:11 406831 kernel: [3715446.849786] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033

May  2 22:34:11 406831 kernel: [3715446.889882] CR2: 00007fdac187ca80 CR3: 000000058cda1000 CR4: 00000000000006e0

May  2 22:34:11 406831 kernel: [3715446.968627] DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000

May  2 22:34:11 406831 kernel: [3715447.049676] DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000ffff0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400

May  2 22:34:11 406831 kernel: [3715447.130842] Process apache2 (pid: 19118, threadinfo ffff88060b852000, task ffff88058c11c4a0)

May  2 22:34:11 406831 kernel: [3715447.212160] **Stack**:

May  2 22:34:11 406831 kernel: [3715447.251311]  00007fdac0088280 ffff880be1ca5ec8 000000000000000f 0000000000000000

May  2 22:34:11 406831 kernel: [3715447.331017]  ffff88060b853e28 ffffffff8105f2e1 0000000000000000 0000000081a4c270

May  2 22:34:11 406831 kernel: [3715447.412179]  ffff88060b853e38 0000000000000282 0000000000000021 ffff880b92505ec8

May  2 22:34:11 406831 kernel: [3715447.493302] **Call Trace**:

May  2 22:34:11 406831 kernel: [3715447.533014]  [] try_to_wake_up+0x31/0x3e0

May  2 22:34:11 406831 kernel: [3715447.573262]  [] wake_up_process+0x15/0x20

May  2 22:34:11 406831 kernel: [3715447.612669]  [] wake_up_sem_queue_do+0x37/0x60

May  2 22:34:11 406831 kernel: [3715447.651327]  [] freeary+0x1c6/0x200

May  2 22:34:11 406831 kernel: [3715447.689083]  [] semctl_down.clone.5+0xbb/0x110

May  2 22:34:11 406831 kernel: [3715447.726360]  [] ? sys_kill+0x7e/0x90

May  2 22:34:11 406831 kernel: [3715447.762833]  [] ? fput+0x25/0x30

May  2 22:34:11 406831 kernel: [3715447.798362]  [] sys_semctl+0x7e/0xd0

May  2 22:34:11 406831 kernel: [3715447.833126]  [] system_call_fastpath+0x16/0x1b

May  2 22:34:11 406831 kernel: [3715447.867350] Code: 00 48 c7 c3 00 3d 01 00 49 89 fc 49 89 f5 9c 58 0f 1f 44 00 00 48 89 c2 fa 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 49 89 55 00 49 8b 44 24 08 49 89 de <8b> 40 18 4c 03 34 c5 80 c8 aa 81 4c 89 f7 e8 53 4e 57 00 49 8b

May  2 22:34:11 406831 kernel: [3715447.970388] RIP  [] task_rq_lock+0x4a/0xa0

May  2 22:34:11 406831 kernel: [3715448.004042]  RSP

May  2 22:34:11 406831 kernel: [3715448.083219] ---[ end trace 244a1ec2d6f912fa ]---

May  2 22:35:01 406831 CRON[19243]: (root) CMD (bash /home/admin/log-children)

May  2 22:36:01 406831 CRON[19256]: (root) CMD (bash /home/admin/log-children)

---

Second Freeze

it too happened after we reloaded apache after making changes to .htaccess

this time syslog showed

**406831 kernel: imklog 4.6.4, log source = /proc/kmsg started.**

this was the only message logged before restart.
can anyone help in finding the cause.Is this indicate a hardware problem or a kernel bug??

Answer (score 1):

Random rebooting/freezing with different log messages may indicate hardware problem. Check your power condition, test memory, check for cpu overheating or other hardware problem.

Comment: doesn't this indicate a kernel issue??like locking of kernel.

Comment: Less likely. I haven't found matching issue in ubuntu. The kernel/distro/hardware you are using is common enough. So the odds are that reason is in hardware.